# Folium don't run on my jupyter notebook(local)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, folium

i'm trying a two hours solving this problem, my mind is confucius!

I'm run Jupyter Notebook on my laptop(local). But on python is working, in my jupyter show this error;

im trying on py2 and py3.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-173c1173bf1c> in <module>()
----> 1 import folium

/home/vitor/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/folium/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 import warnings
      7 
----> 8 import branca
      9 from branca.colormap import (ColorMap, LinearColormap, StepColormap)
     10 from branca.element import (

/home/vitor/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/branca/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 import branca.colormap as colormap
      2 import branca.element as element
      3 
      4 from ._version import get_versions
      5 

/home/vitor/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/branca/colormap.py in <module>()
     13 from jinja2 import Template
     14 
---> 15 from branca.element import ENV, Figure, JavascriptLink, MacroElement
     16 from branca.utilities import legend_scaler
     17 

/home/vitor/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/branca/element.py in <module>()
     11 import warnings
     12 from collections import OrderedDict
---> 13 from urllib.request import urlopen
     14 from uuid import uuid4
     15 

ImportError: No module named request
```

Thx

Comment: Install request package: `pip install -U request`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see error on installation folium, this is confused!

[image: jupyter on my computer]